# Gapfill pandas dataframe using values from same column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
   a1 a2  a3    b1
0  0  0  12   NaN
1  0  3  NaN  NaN
2  2  3  1    NaN
```

In the dataframe `df` above, I want to gap-fill column `a3` and `b1` using median of values from the same columns in another dataframe `df2` with the same columns but different values.

```
   a1  a2  a3  b1
0  0  0  2  6 
1  0  3  3  7
2  2  3  4  8
```

I tried this:
`df.fillna(df2.median(), inplace=True)`, but I am not sure if it does what I want

Comment: Maybe you should first be sure of what you want ;) What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does what you want.

The median of `a3` in `df2` is 3, the median of `b1` in `df2` is 7.

```
>>> df.fillna(df2.median())
   a1  a2    a3   b1
0   0   0  12.0  7.0
1   0   3   3.0  7.0
2   2   3   1.0  7.0
```

So it looks like good, no?